# Run a python server on a background

Tags: python

I am using [gevent-socketio](https://github.com/abourget/gevent-socketio) to to push real time data from a python script to a browser. However I would like it to work interactively from the interpreter so that the server would continue to run in the background. Some pseudo code:

```
#start server with the application and keep it running on the background
server_inst=MyAppServer()

#send data to the sever that pushes it to a browser (prints "foo" to the browser)
server_inst.send_data('foo')
```

Having looked at threading I am still confused how it could/should be done. Any pointers appriciated.

Answer (score 0):

Is there a reason to have the server and the console program as the same process?

If not I would suggest the use of two separate processes and named pipes. If this solution is not ideal for whatever reason can you please give more details.

Anyway, here is some code that might be useful to you for implementing a Pipe class. I'm not sure exactly what form the data that you need to communicate looks like so you could make the Pipe class abstract some simple protocol and/or use pickle.

```
def __init__(self,sPath):
    """
    create the fifo. if it already exists just associate with it
    """
    self.sPath = sPath
    if not os.path.exists(sPath):
        try:
            os.mkfifo(sPath)
        except:
            raise Exception('cannot mkfifo at path \n {0}'.format(sPath))
    self.iFH = os.open(sPath,os.O_RDWR | os.O_NONBLOCK)
    self.iFHBlocking = os.open(sPath,os.O_RDWR)

def base_read(self,iLen,blocking=False):
    iFile = self.iFHBlocking if blocking else self.iFH
    while not self.ready_for_reading():
        import time
        time.sleep(0.5)

    lBytes = ''.encode('utf-8')
    while len(lBytes)<iLen:
        self.lock()
        try:
            lBytes += os.read(iFile,1)
            self.unlock()
        except OSError as e:
            self.unlock()
            if e.errno == 11:
                import time
                time.sleep(0.5)
            else:
                raise e

    return lBytes

def base_write(self,lBytes,blocking = False):
    iFile = self.iFHBlocking if blocking else self.iFH
    while not self.ready_for_writing():
        import time
        time.sleep(0.5)

    while True:
        self.lock()
        try:
            iBytesWritten =  os.write(iFile, lBytes)
            self.unlock()
            break
        except OSError as e:
            self.unlock()
            if e.errno in [35,11]:
                import time
                time.sleep(0.5)
            else:
                raise

    if iBytesWritten < len(lBytes):
        self.base_write(lBytes[iBytesWritten:],blocking)

def get_lock_dir(self):
    return '{0}_lockdir__'.format(self.sPath)

def lock(self):
    while True:
        try:
            os.mkdir(self.get_lock_dir())
            return
        except OSError as e:
            if e.errno != 17:
                raise e

def unlock(self):
    try:
        os.rmdir(self.get_lock_dir())
    except OSError as e:
        if e.errno != 2:
            raise e

def ready_for_reading(self):
    lR,lW,lX = select.select([self.iFH,],[],[],self.iTimeout)
    if not lR:
        return False
    lR,lW,lX = select.select([self.iFHBlocking],[],[],self.iTimeout)
    if not lR:
        return False
    return True

def ready_for_writing(self):
    lR,lW,lX = select.select([],[self.iFH,],[],self.iTimeout)
    if not lW:
        return False
    return True
```

I have a more complete implementation of the class that I am willing to share but I think the protocol I abstract with it would probably be useless to you... How you would use this is create an instance in your server and your console application using the same path. You then use base_read and base_write to do the dirty work. All the other stuff here is to avoid weird race conditions.

Hope this helps.